# iframe and communicating between them

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page, index, that has the below content and iframe setup:

index page:

```
<html>
<body>

<iframe src=".." id="leftFrame"></frame>
<iframe src="mainFrame.html" id="mainFrame"></frame>

</body>

</html>
```

mainFrame.html:

```
<div class="hidden" id="hiddenStuff">
....
</div>
```

Now in the mainFrame I am loading some content in a hidden div.

Is it possible to fetch that content from mainFrame.html and display it in the index, **that is triggered from the mainFrame via javascript**?

i.e. once the mainFrame loads, it will make a call via javascript to the parent iframe to fetch the contents of #hiddenStuff and then display it in the index page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible if the parent and mainFrame are both on the same domain.

**Parent/index:**

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

function updateContent(content)
{
    $('#content').html(content);
}

document.domain = "yourdomain.com";

</script>

<iframe src=".." id="leftFrame"></frame>
<iframe src="mainFrame.html" id="mainFrame"></frame>

<div id="content"> </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**mainFrame/child:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.domain = "yourdomain.com";

$(document).ready(function(){

    // on page load, trigger the update
    var content = $('#hiddenStuff').html();

    try
    {
        parent.updateContent(content);
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        // couldn't call the parent, handle the exception
    }

});

</script>

<div class="hidden" id="hiddenStuff">
....
</div>
```

Keep in mind when dealing with raw HTML into elements you need to consider the possibility of XSS if any of the content comes from user input.